# How to assign the results of a row to different variables using PDO in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table

```
id    url    count
1     www.    6
2     www.    9
3     www.    11
4
```

and so on

I want to display the count next to a link in my webpage and therefore I am using the statements below to assign "count" to a variable for a specific id.

```
$stmt1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clickcounter WHERE id = 1");
while ($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$count1=$row['count'];
}
$stmt2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clickcounter WHERE id = 2");
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$count2=$row['count'];
}
$stmt3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clickcounter WHERE id = 3");
while ($row = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$count3=$row['count'];
}
```

and so on

I have plenty of id in my table. 
Is there a better way to do this or do I have to write these statements over and over again.

Basically I want to assign the values of "count" to a variable so that I can use them in my webpage at different locations.

Comment: how match IDs do you have in you table?? 5? 10? Do you need vars $count... , or a list of urls and an number of clicks?

Comment: Currently I have 15 but that is bound to increase as I add more urls. I just want to get the number of clicks assigned to a variable so that I can display it in my webpage where ever I may need it.

Comment: I am afraid not. I am still unable to assign values to different variables. Using the method you suggested, I only get one value.

Comment: @user2950355 My answer should work now as the `id`'s are now added to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can make a block with url list and add pager with button "next list" or so.

For example:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
$per_page = 10;
$url_list = "";
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clickcounter LIMIT ".($page * $per_page).", 10");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$url_list .= $row['url']." : ".$row['count']."<br />\n";
}

// view url list

print $url_list;
```

You can save it in external file and use javascript (like jQuery) for display it in you page and change pages with "onclick" function :)